# Android - Volley set specific port

Tags: android, http, port, android-volley, http-request

A pretty simple question, but failed to find any proper answer for it;

Is it possible to set a specific port to use when doing a (GET) http request with Volley as library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems adding  ":{portnumber}" to the url works just fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
But some source code editing is required.

Volley's `RequestQueue` uses either an `HttpClientStack` for Android version 8, or a `HurlStack` for 9 and up, to perform the actual request. In both of these classes, the string you provide as a URL when you create a request is turned into a `URL` or `URI` object. You can edit their constructors to set the port you want.